# Intransitive equivalent for "to make thirsty/sleepy/etc."

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a less ambiguous way of saying "I'm glad we're out, those meetings always make you sleepy" where "you" means "everybody in general", without using synonyms ("grueling", "exhausting", etc.), and using other pronouns (like "one" or "us")?

Something like "good exercise is always tiring".

Comment: In speech, disambiguation occurs by, for the unusual non-generic 'you' usage, giving 'you' far more emphasis or by the addition of a vocative ("I'm glad we're out – those meetings always make you sleepy, grandad").  "His lectures are _so_ somniferous / soporific" are probably best left unused. I think you're left with attempted witticisms ("Her meetings work better than 'Drowsidrops' "). // Requests for words meaning hunger-inducing, thirst-inducing etc should be posted separately.

Comment: This sounds OK: "I'm glad we're out, those meetings always make one sleepy"

Comment: Why not use "everybody" instead of "you"?

Comment: Soporific and somniferous are both good dictionary-words and would fit in more elevated prose but would certainly be unusual in casual speech. You have a choice, to rephrase with a different pronoun or subject, or rewrite, or use something unusual. Unfortunately there isn't much detail in the question about what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but if you really insist, you can use *induce*.

> I'm glad we're out, those meetings are so sleepiness-inducing

This works a bit better with words like *thirst*, where there is a more natural noun form available.

Comment: That's why I kept it to a 'comment'.